# Issue with "ftp" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, ftp

I wanted to simply put the text

```
ftp 1.1.1.1
```

into a cell in a large existing Excel spreadsheet.

I did not want to kick off ftp from the spreadsheet.

When I went to save the spreadsheet, I got the message:
Errors were detected while saving '...'. Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in a new file, click Continue. To cancel saving the file, click Cancel.

I didn't see an indication that the ftp text was the line which was causing the issue.

I eventually found the line which was causing the issue.

Then, I added a single quote to the front of the text, as a work-around.

```
'ftp 1.1.1.1
```

I thought the error was probably caused by one of the lines I recently added or changed, so that narrowed it down a little. Is there any way other than trial and error to find which recently added or changed line is causing this type of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hyperlink with an invalid address field is causing this issue.

Consider using VBA code to find (and remove) invalid hyperlinks.

```
Sub RemoveInvalidHyperlinks()
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    For Each hl In Cells.Hyperlinks
        'If Address contains a space, it is invalid.
        If InStr(hl.Address, " ") > 0 Then
            hl.Delete 'Note: the text within the cell will remain.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: The code could be modified to highlight, notify, or otherwise flag an invalid Hyperlink.

You may also consider disabling the following: Settings, Proofing, AutoCorrect, AutoFormat As You Type, Internet and network paths with hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

Excel is interpreting your text as a hyperlink ( a bad hyperlink) and is trying to fix this.